# How can I compare two XML objects in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have two XML objects:

```
$objectWeb  = irm "http://server/webservice"   ## created by web service call
$objectFile = [XML](get-content ./myfile.xml)  ## returned from file
```

I want to compare them to determine whether I need to continue on in my script. Normally all nodes match, but I do need to output any nodes that don't. I would normally use `compare-object`, but it only compares the top nodes `<xml>` and `<response>`:

```
compare $objectWeb $objectFile  ## no output even on mismatched files

PS > $objectWeb
xml                            response
---                            --------
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" response
```

Normally I could compare the OuterXml properties of both objects, but get-content strips all whitespace/linebreaks

The objects look like this, with many sub-nodes below `<message>`:

```
PS > $objectFile.OuterXML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><result>succeed</result><messages><message><type>info</type>...</message></messages></response>

PS > $objectWeb.OuterXML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result>succeed</result>
  <messages>
    <message>
      <type>info</type>
      ...
    </message>
  </messages>
</response>
```

I got as far as reading them as text instead, then splitting on the nodes like so:

```
compare $objectWeb.outerxml.split("`n") (get-content ./myfile -raw).split("`n")
```

So now (with some extra trimming of newlines) `compare-object` actually compares each node and shows me which ones are different, but I lose all the XML path data with this method, which causes problems if I need to know the parent nodes.

Is there some way to compare each node as actual XML objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using microsoft's XMLDiff tool. I see it's been rebuilt into some other packages since I made this originally, but I'm using version `1.0.8.28`:

```
#requires -modules xmldiffpatch
function Compare-XML {
    Param(
    [XML[]]$ReferenceObject,
    [XML[]]$DifferenceObject,
    [String] $DiffGramPath,
    [Bool] $IgnoreChildOrder = $true,
    [Bool] $IgnoreComments   = $false,
    [Bool] $IgnoreDtd        = $false,
    [Bool] $IgnoreNamespaces = $false,
    [Bool] $IgnorePI         = $false,
    [Bool] $IgnorePrefixes   = $false,
    [Bool] $IgnoreWhitespace = $true,
    [Bool] $IgnoreXmlDecl    = $false
    )
    # convert PowerShell's default [System.Xml.XMLDocument] to [System.Xml.XmlReader]
    $refXDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $ReferenceObject
    $difXDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $DifferenceObject
    $diff    = New-Object Microsoft.XmlDiffPatch.XmlDiff -Property @{
        IgnoreChildOrder = $IgnoreChildOrder
        IgnoreComments   = $IgnoreComments
        IgnoreDtd        = $IgnoreDtd
        IgnoreNamespaces = $IgnoreNamespaces
        IgnorePI         = $IgnorePI
        IgnorePrefixes   = $IgnorePrefixes
        IgnoreWhitespace = $IgnoreWhitespace
        IgnoreXmlDecl    = $IgnoreXmlDecl
    }

    # Try and create a diffgram showing the differences
    if ($DiffGramPath) {
        $XmlSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings -Property @{
            Indent = $true
            IndentChars = '  '
            NewLineChars = "`r`n"
            NewLineHandling = [System.Xml.NewLineHandling]::Replace
        }
        $DgWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create('C:\temp\diff.xml',$XmlSettings)
        $diff.Compare($refXDoc, $difXDoc, $DgWriter)
        $DgWriter.Flush()
        $DgWriter.Close()
    }
    # Else return only t/f
    Else { $diff.Compare($refXDoc, $difXDoc) }
}
```

And usage looks like this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml.Linq") | Out-Null
Import-Module "C:\path\to\XMLDiff\xmldiffpatch.dll"

$xml1 = [xml](get-content "C:\path\to\1.xml")
$xml2 = [xml](get-content "C:\path\to\2.xml")

# outputs Boolean true/false:
Compare-XML $xml1 $xml2


# Example: try to count how many changes exist:
Compare-XML $xml1 $xml2 -DiffGramPath 'C:\temp\diffgram.xml'
$result = Get-Content 'C:\temp\diffgram.xml'
$changes = $result.Split("`n") | 
    Select-String -Pattern "(<xd:change|<xd:add|<xd:remove)" |
    Measure-Object

Write-Output "$($changes.Count) Changes found"

# Outputs:
False
6 changes found
```

**Note:** This tool has some known bugs and is a bit slow, so be careful of larger XML files.

Comment: The Assembly is based on .NET 1.0 - how did you manage to load the dll with newer versions of PowerShell based on .NET 4.5?

Comment: @PeterXX I have no trouble loading the dll into powershell. I've updated my answer with everything I use now, and it works reliably for me in PS versions `Desktop  5.1`  and `Core 7.1.3`

Comment: The reason for the error was that the dll file was not unblocked. After I unblocked it loading with Add-Type was no problem.